# Database.SqlQuery convert all return values to string

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a question about getting data from a database using a raw SQL query:

```
DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(runQuery).FirstOrDefault();
```

The question is, how to convert all returned values to a `String`, or how to handle different returned data types using `Database.SqlQuery`

Comment: You could have them come back as `object` and `ToString()` them. It's a little unclear as to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to create a .net function that will send raw sql queries to the DB and will receive back requested data (returned data could be with different data types)

Comment: Have you looked into Stored Procedures?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to create a class and map the columns that returns your query with primitive data type properties declared in that class,eg:

```
// SQL version of the above LINQ code.
string query = "SELECT EnrollmentDate, COUNT(*) AS StudentCount "
        + "FROM Person "
        + "WHERE Discriminator = 'Student' "
        + "GROUP BY EnrollmentDate";
IEnumerable<EnrollmentDateGroup> data = db.Database.SqlQuery<EnrollmentDateGroup>(query);
```

And your class would be something like this:

```
public class EnrollmentDateGroup
{
  public int StudentCount {get;set;}
  public DateTime EnrollmentDate {get;set;}
}
```

You can find the list of primitive data types you can use to map  Microsoft SQL Server data types in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx)